# some hrefs of my ecommerce on mobile devices do not work properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, mobile

I have a problem with my e-commerce site and mobile devices, http://www.shoppingverde.it

I spent hours trying to fix clicks on my carousels .. when I noticed that also the button on the top right "Carrello" (My Cart in english) has the same problem:

Clicking on certain links on mobile device activates :hover instead of the link. Or better, that was the problem I thought, until I discovered the same bug on "Carrello", that DOES NOT have an :hover effect.

I really can't get rid of why it cant be clicked on mobiles.

Tried adding cursor:pointer and some other fixes I found around on google, but nothing seems to solve it.
Some infos:

- if you do a long tap on "carrello" (or any other link that doesn't open) on my iPhone \ iPad it asks you to open a link in a new window or in the same (so it detects there is a link nad you can open it in this way)
- if you use device mode on chrome emulating an iPhone \ iPad it works (but it doesn't on real iOS device)
- Links just on left to log-in or register are actually working on mobiles

If someone can help me I would be happy, since I am loosing time on this from  2 days :(

Comment: Please provide some code snippet for your issue.

Comment: I can paste you the inspect on firebug of the "carrello" element, may it be helpful?